# Update redis server from 1.2.6 to latest

Tags: redis

I need to update redis server.

I found a way to save DB on disk and after restore it, but my question is will new redis server have problems with read old DB structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The version of the dump file is encoded in the first 9 characters. So the following command can be used to check it:

```
$ head -1 dump.rdb | cut -c1-9
REDIS0002
```

Redis 1-2-6 used version 1 of the dump file (it can read and write only version 1)

Redis 2-4-6 is using version 2. However, it is able to read both version 1 and version 2 files. Version 2 happen to be backward compatible with version 1 anyway.

To upgrade, you can just read the version 1 dump file with a recent Redis release, and then dump the file again (it will be written with version 2 format). The new file may be smaller due to some optimizations available with recent Redis versions and the version 2 format.

Optionally, you can check the integrity of the dump file before starting the 2-4 Redis instance by using the redis-check-dump command:

```
$ ../redis-2.4.4/src/redis-check-dump dump.rdb 
==== Processed 19033 valid opcodes (in 639641 bytes) ===========================
```

This is a pure read-only utility, it cannot harm the dump file.